# Disqus OAuth Invalid Grant

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-2.0, disqus

I keep getting this error when I try to use OAuth with Disqus:

```
{"error_description":"Invalid parameter: redirect_uri","error":"invalid_grant"}
```

My Code looks like this- Example 1:

```
$oauth2token_url = 'https://disqus.com/api/oauth/2.0/access_token/';
        $redirect_uri = 'http://www.example.com/';
        $clienttoken_post = array(
            "grant_type" => 'authorization_code',
            "client_id" => PVConfiguration::getConfiguration('disqus') -> public_key,
            "client_secret" => PVConfiguration::getConfiguration('disqus') -> private_key,
            "redirect_uri" => $redirect_uri,
            "code" => $this -> registry -> get['code']
        );

        $curl = curl_init($oauth2token_url);

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $clienttoken_post);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        $json_response = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);

        print_r($json_response);
```

Or this - Example 2:

```
$url = 'https://disqus.com/api/oauth/2.0/access_token/';
        $fields = array(
            'grant_type'    =>  'authorization_code',
            'client_id'     =>  PVConfiguration::getConfiguration('disqus') -> public_key,
            'client_secret' =>  PVConfiguration::getConfiguration('disqus') -> private_key,
            'redirect_uri'  =>  'http://www.example.com/',
            //'scope' => 'read,write,email',
            'code'          =>  $this -> registry -> get['code'],
        );

        $fields_string  = '';
        //url-ify the data for the POST
        foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
        rtrim($fields_string, '&');

        //open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

        //execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        //close connection
        curl_close($ch);

        print_r($result);

        exit();
```

Can anyone provide any direction?

Comment: Are you sure that the authorization keys are okay?

Comment: What do you mean by ok?

Comment: Are they the correct ones as provided by Disqus? Also, try leaving out redirect_uri.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Documentation is here:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.3

But the problem stems from bad api error message. The redirect uri to get the code must be the exact same uri when requesting authorization.